# Pyqtgraph click outside the image

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

I would like to know when I clicked outside the image matrix (on the screen attached, I would like to know when I clicked in the black space).

[image]

The goal of my app is to know when I clicked outside the image box, and also to know if I clicked on the left, top, right or bottom side of the black space around the image.

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np

matrix = np.random.randint(1,10,(100, 100))
print(matrix)

app = pg.mkQApp()

win = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget()

img = pg.ImageItem()
img.setImage(matrice)
view = win.addViewBox()
view.addItem(img)

def mouse_double_click(event):
            print(event.pos())
            print(event.scenePos())
            print(event.screenPos())

img.scene().sigMouseClicked.connect(mouse_double_click)
win.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.exec()
```

Answer (score 0):

`img.mapFromScene(event.scenePos())` returns a point, from which the x and y position can be retrieved, so the function can be changed to this:

```
def mouse_double_click(event):
    pos = img.mapFromScene(event.scenePos())
    x, y = int(pos.x()), int(pos.y())
    print(f"Click at x = {x}, y = {y}")
    position = ""
    if y >= 100:
        position += "top"
    elif y <= 0:
        position += "bottom"
    if x >= 100:
        position += "right"
    elif x <= 0:
        position += "left"
    if position:
        print(f"The click was on the {position}")
```